# android: Upgrade My Library from android to androidx but not found this class SlideCallback

Tags: java, android, androidx, leanback

This is my code in old library

**android.support.v17.leanback.transition.SlideCallback;**

updated to

**androidx.leanback.transition;**

how can I convert this code?

```
import androidx.leanback.transition.*;

public class VGDetailsTitleTransitionHelper {

    final static  SlideCallback sSlideCallback = new SlideCallback() {
        @Override
        public boolean getSlide(View view, boolean appear, int[] edge, float[] distance) {
            edge[0] = TransitionHelper.SLIDE_TOP;
            Log.v("getSlide details", "" + view.getHeight());
            distance[0] = view.getHeight();
            return true;
        }
    };

    

}
```